# Ошибки в Qt Creator: no member named 'setModal', no member named 'exec'

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Создал два окна: `mainwindow` и `settings`, при нажатии кнопки в `mainwindow` должно открываться окно `settings`, делал один в один, как в видеоуроке и ничего не работает.

settings.h

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
#define SETTINGS_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class Settings;
}

class Settings : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Settings(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Settings();

private:
    Ui::Settings *ui;
};

#endif // SETTINGS_H
```

settings.cpp

```
#include "settings.h"
#include "ui_settings.h"

Settings::Settings(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Settings)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Settings::~Settings()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void on_actionSettings_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "settings.h"
   

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_actionSettings_clicked()
{
    Settings settings;
    settings.setModal(true);   error: no member named 'setModal' in 'Settings'
    settings.exec();           error: no member named 'exec' in 'Settings'             
}
```

Comment: @Helg1980 что значит "ничего не работает"? Почему у вас в названии вопроса явно фигурирует ошибка компиляции, но в самом вопросе вы пишите так, будто программа у вас собралась?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Settings` наследуйте от `QDialog`, там есть эти член-функции

Comment: Это помогло. Спасибо!